# JavaScript Array.find Regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have 2 arrays of keywords. I need to figure out the index of the first keyword in array 1 that matches any of the keywords in array 2.

Examples

```
array1 = ['spinach', 'avocado', 'milk', 'beans', 'ham', 'eggs', 'cheese'];
array2 = ['cheese', 'milk'];
```

In this example, milk at index 2 would be the first match, and I want to return the index of 2.

Can I use array.find() to return the index of the first match, if each element is compared to array2 using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and check the second array with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var array1 = ['spinach', 'avocado', 'milk', 'beans', 'ham', 'eggs', 'cheese'],
    array2 = ['cheese', 'milk'];
    
console.log(array1.findIndex(v => array2.includes(v)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find matching index using `findIndex()` and `includes()`:

```
let index = array1.findIndex(s => array2.includes(s));
```

**Demo:**

```js
let a1 = ['spinach', 'avocado', 'milk', 'beans', 'ham', 'eggs', 'cheese'],
    a2 = ['cheese', 'milk'];

let index = a1.findIndex(s => a2.includes(s));

console.log(index);
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.findIndex` instead:

```js
const array1 = ['spinach', 'avocado', 'milk', 'beans', 'ham', 'eggs', 'cheese'];
const array2 = ['cheese', 'milk'];
const foundIndex = array1.findIndex(elm => array2.includes(elm));
console.log(foundIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a regular expression from `array2` and then use `Array.findIndex`:

```
var re = new RegExp('^'+array2.join('|')+'$');
var found = array1.findIndex(function (e) { return re.test(e); });
```